# C#: организация работы сокета

Tags: c#, сокет, сокеты

Добрый день!

Столкнулся я с интересной задачей.
Требуется вот что сделать:

В общих чертах: отправить 3 сообщения через сокет на сервер.

После каждого нашего сообщения ждем ответного от сервера.

Т.е. графически вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. нужно дождаться ответа на очередное наше сообщение, потом отправлять новое.

Я пробовал сделать потоками, но не получилось (отправлялось msg2 во время того как ждали ответа на первое, например.)

Подскажите пожалуйста, структуру кода, которая должна быть в таком случае. Я сейчас об этом думаю:

```
void SendMessage(Byte[] msg)
{
while (true)
{
     //отправляем сообщение, например 1
     socketSend(msg);
     //ждем ответа на сообщение 1
     string key1 = ReceiveMessage();
  }
}
 void ReceiveMessage()
        {
            try
            {

                byte[] sizeinfo = new byte[4];

                //read the size of the message
                int totalread = 0, currentread = 0;
                if (socketClient.Poll(10000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                {
                    currentread = totalread = socketClient.Receive(sizeinfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }

                while (totalread < sizeinfo.Length && currentread > 0)
                {
                    currentread = socketClient.Receive(sizeinfo,
                              totalread, //offset into the buffer
                              sizeinfo.Length - totalread, //max amount to read
                              SocketFlags.None);

                    totalread += currentread;
                }

                int messagesize = 0;
                String sizeinfoString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sizeinfo);


                if (!Int32.TryParse(sizeinfoString, out messagesize))
                {
                    throw new Exception("receive: " + "Unable to parse length :{0}" + sizeinfoString);
                }


                byte[] data = new byte[messagesize];

                //read the first chunk of data
                totalread = 0;
                currentread = totalread = socketClient.Receive(data,
                             totalread, //offset into the buffer
                            data.Length - totalread, //max amount to read
                            SocketFlags.None);

                //if we didn't get the entire message, read some more until we do
                while (totalread < messagesize && currentread > 0)
                {
                    currentread = socketClient.Receive(data,
                             totalread, //offset into the buffer
                            data.Length - totalread, //max amount to read
                            SocketFlags.None);
                    totalread += currentread;
                }
                //TO-DO: Здесь можно организовать очередь

                //data - текст входящего сообщения
                Console.WriteLine("Key:\n" + data);
                return data;
            }
            catch (SocketException exc)
            {
                throw new Exception("receive: "+exc.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw new Exception("receive: " +  exc.Message);
            }


        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: посмотри как устроена работа websocket

Comment: насколько я знаю это те еж сокеты + асинхронностью. Вы думаете, это актуально в данном случае?

Comment: просто как применение - приняв асинхронно ответ с сервера проверяем "масcив очереди отправления" - и отправляем очередное сообщение серверу. удаляем из этого массива одно значение, спим, ожидая следующее от сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вам обязательно писать именно на сокетах? Есть же `TcpClient`.

Для начала, вспомогательные функции:

```
async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync(NetworkStream s, uint nbytes)
{
    var buf = new byte[nbytes];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nbytes)
        readpos += await s.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
    return buf;
}
```

Ваши данные посылаются с префиксом, содержащим размер? Отлично.

```
async Task<byte[]> ReadMessageAsync(NetworkStream s)
{
    // принимаем байты длины
    var sizeBytes = await ReadFromStreamAsync(s, 4);
    // превращаем в размер
    var size = BitConverter.ToUint32(sizeBytes);
    // принимаем данные и возвращаем их
    return await ReadFromStreamAsync(s, size);
}

async Task<string> ReadMessageAsync(NetworkStream s, Encoding enc)
{
    var bytes = await ReadMessageAsync(s);
    return enc.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Ну и конечно вам надо уметь послать данные:

```
Task SendToStreamAsync(NetworkStream s, byte[] data)
{
    return s.WriteAsync(data, 0, dataLength);
}

async Task SendMessageAsync(NetworkStream s, byte[] data)
{
    // разбираем блину на байты
    var sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
    // посылаем длину
    await SendToStreamAsync(s, sizeBytes);
    // посылаем данные
    await SendToStreamAsync(s, data);
}

async Task SendMessageAsync(NetworkStream s, string message, Encoding enc)
{
    await SendMessageAsync(s, enc.GetBytes(message));
}
```

Теперь ваша логика простая.

```
async Task Run()
{
    using (var client = new TcpClient())
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
        using (var s = client.GetStream())
        {
            await SendMessageAsync(s, "msg1", Encoding.ASCII);
            var key1 = ReadMessageAsync(s, Encoding.ASCII);
            await SendMessageAsync(s, "msg2", Encoding.ASCII);
            var key2 = ReadMessageAsync(s, Encoding.ASCII);
            await SendMessageAsync(s, "msg3", Encoding.ASCII);
            var key3 = ReadMessageAsync(s, Encoding.ASCII);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот и всё. Всю асинхронность и выпрямление логики сделает за вас async/await. Потоки не нужны.